# how to change checkbox property in installscript?

Tags: installshield, installscript, installshield-2008

ive made dialog that shows two checkboxes.

i made the dialog with AskOptions function, like this :

```
nResult = AskOptions(NONEXCLUSIVE,szProduct ,
                     "Install Client", Client,
                     "Install Server",Server);
```

now, i have condition that check if the user has administrator privileges , if he doesnt has , i want to disable the second (server) checkbox.

how should i change his "Enabled" property through installscript ?

thanks,

shacharsa

Answer (score 0):

The better way is modify AskOptions dialogs' source code.

Comment: how should i do this ? how can i change the property of the checkbox in the AskOptions function ? i saw that when i go the AskOptions dialog under the Dialogs view there is a Enabled property .. this is the propery that i should change..